# Changing NSString value (displayed as number) to two decimal places and make a percentage

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsnumber

When I retrieve my `JSONResponse` i retrieve a number that appears as 0.2434309606330154. This is the number I want, however it isn't in the format that I want. It is set up in a way that with three other response it equals to 1.

I've tried converting it to an `NSNumber` but it didn't work.

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{
                             @"data": text.text,
                             };

NSMutableString *parameterString = [NSMutableString string];
for (NSString *key in [parameters allKeys]) {
    if ([parameterString length]) {
        [parameterString appendString:@"&"];
    }
    [parameterString appendFormat:@"%@=%@", key, parameters[key]];
}

NSLog(@"A: %@", jsonResponse[@"results"][@"A"]);
ALabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",jsonResponse[@"results"][@"A"]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",jsonResponse[@"results"][@"A"]];
 CGFloat float = [string floatValue];

ALabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f",float];
```

In Swift 1.2:

```
self.ALabel?.text = NSString(format: "%.02f%%", string.floatValue) as String
```

Comment: when I tried adding the CGFloat float = [string floatValue]; it comes up with a Parse issue "Cannot combine with previous declaration specifier"

Comment: What's the reason for creating a new string instance in the first line? I do not think that this is necessary.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad just for explanation purpose. I know all of the above task can be done in one line :)

Comment: I thought so. This was the reason for my Q. But `NSString *string = jsonResponse[@"results"][@"A"];` would have the same explanation detail.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad You are right. you can edit it if you want.

Comment: Of course not. Your answer is correct and explains the solution in a good manner. No reason for a edit or down vote.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",jsonResponse[@"results"][@"A"]];
ALabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f%%",string.floatValue];
```

Here output will be - 0.24%